# txtAddress is not declared. I cannot reference TextBox inside of AJAX .NET VB Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, drop-down-menu

Trying to fill a few textboxes using AJAX, VB .NET:

```
<div align="left">

<asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlAddresses" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate runat="server">
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlVenueAddresses" Width="264px" Height="24px" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="ddlVenueAddresses_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="admin" BackColor="Transparent" DataTextField="VenueName" DataValueField="VenueAddress"></asp:dropdownlist> (optional)
                <br />
                <input name="txtAddress" id="txtAddress" type="text" size="70" maxlength="100"  value='<%= Request.Form.Get("txtAddress")%>'/>
                <br />
                <input name="txtGoogleAddress" type="text" size="70" maxlength="100"   value='<%= Request.Form.Get("txtGoogleAddress")%>'/>
                <br />
                <input name="txtGoogleCity" type="text" size="70" maxlength="100"   value='<%= Request.Form.Get("txtGoogleCity")%>'/>
                <br />
                <input name="txtGoogleState" type="text" size="70" maxlength="100"   value='<%= Request.Form.Get("txtGoogleState")%>'/>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


        </div>
    </td>
```

dropdown list gets populated and when item is picked, code stops on breakpoint where it should. But stepping through I get error when trying to just add simple "xxxx"s to textbox as a test:

```
 Public Sub ddlVenueAddresses_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

            Dim txtAddressFound As TextBox
            txtAddressFound = pnlAddresses.FindControl("txtAddress")

            txtAddressFound.Text = "xxxxx"

        End Sub
```

txtAddressFound is Null and when trying to set it to "xxxxx" I get this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

If I just trying to set txtAddress.Text = "xxxx" with no FindControl method, it says it doesn't exist:

```
? txtAddress
'txtAddress' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

Totally lost. This application has been working for years, I just wanted to use Ajax to populate some address stuff.
Does anyone have any ideas?
I have tons of textboxes on this form (not using AJAX on them). I also put this at the top under Inherits System.Web.UI.Page with no luck.

```
Protected WithEvents txtAddress As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to access client side control `txtAddress` from Server side script.

In ASP.NET, control should be

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="Server" />
```

This way you can access it from Server Side.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="txtAddress" id="txtAddress" runat="server" type="text" size="70" maxlength="100"  value='<%= Request.Form.Get("txtAddress")%>'/>

protected void ddlVenueAddresses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtAddress.Value = "XXXX";
    }
```

I tested the above it works, please check ones. I kept the input html control as is but added runat="server" attribute, I am not sure why are you instantiating a new TextBox to access your input control.

Comment: Did you do this with AJAX? Without a reload? That is what I was trying to do. It looks like a good answer.